# A personal, perceivable watershed moment

Tags: word-choice, expressions, sentence

How would one describe an event in their life positively redefining their future in a significant way?

Further, how would one explain that this "watershed moment" was also perceivable at the time?

As I understand it, a watershed moment cannot really be perceived in real time, but needs a background of events for a reader to understand why the moment was significant.

Example:

> She perceived a turning point when she interacted with the scientists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**watershed**  [your dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/watershed)

> a critical point that marks a division or a change of course; a
>   turning point

Some watershed events or moments require little or no time to earn the appellation.  Consider aliens landing or a continent suddenly sinking away.  Others benefit from hindsight over time.  A personal epiphany as you describe can happen and be noticed, at least by you, in your lifetime.

Other synonyms may include the following: a turning point, a pivotal event, or a defining moment.

Comment: Epiphany, def 3:   https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epiphany

Answer (score -1):

The word you use in the question - watershed - is a matter of inclines and, as you point out, an incline may not be noticeable at the time. Only after much toil upwards, and an apex, will one, eventually, be aware that the incline has changed and the path is easier.

Indeed the very concept is of a slight gradient that determines which way water will, eventually, flow. It is never even a hillock, or water would be inseparably divided right from the start.

But with a '**turning point**' there is no argument. One has reached the end of the road, there is a bend. And one is immediately conscious of a new landscape, a new direction and a new terminus.

Therefore, for life-changing events that are immediately noticeable, at the time, I favour 'turning point' both from the dictionary and from experience.

> a point at which a significant change occurs

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turning%20point)

> the time at which a situation starts to change in an important way:

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turning-point)

> Harvey Weinstein's arrest is a key **turning point**

[CNN - 25 May 2018](https://edition.cnn.com/2018/05/25/opinions/weinstein-arrest-is-a-key-turning-point-polisi/index.html)